# unable to locate package ubuntu-desktop

Tags: 12.04

I've created a new desktop server 12.04 LTS, now it's a fresh install and I've run the commands:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

but when I run

`sudo apt-get install unbuntu-desktop`

the message below is returned.

```
reading package list... done  
building dependency tree  
reading state information... done  
E: unable to locate package unbuntu-desktop
```

I have also checked the source list file and all is correct. Not sure why I am unable to receive this package as other packages I try are fine.

note: I did previously install this unbuntu desktop 2 days ago and wiped the machine then rebuilt with the same steps.

Comment: Did you mistyped the word  "unbuntu-desktop"  here?? If you are looking for exactly what you typed here then this type of package isn't available. the correct package is   "ubuntu-desktop"

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this stupid stupid mistake !!!! its been a long week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that message is copied straight from your terminal, the problem is easy to solve.

The package you are looking for is called **ubuntu-desktop**, not *unbuntu-desktop*.

Comment: Thank you as noted above my eye and spelling are killing me! tho moral of the story is dont use a password like umbungo as it merged in my damn head with ubuntu into unbuntu...... Thanks